# Ayuda obteniendo valor del index en serie de tiempo

Tags: python

Tengo como ejemplo el siguiente dataframe:

```
"""
Datetime     Product1 Product2.....ProductN
01-01-2019 |    0    |   0    ...    0
01-02-2019 |    0    |   5    ...    0
01-03-2019 |    0    |   6    ...    0
01-04-2019 |    0    |   5    ...    0
01-05-2019 |    0    |   5    ...    0
01-06-2019 |    0    |   5    ...    0
01-07-2019 |    12   |   4    ...    0
01-08-2019 |    0    |   7    ...    0
01-09-2019 |    16   |   0    ...    0
01-10-2019 |    15   |   2    ...    0
01-11-2019 |    18   |   6    ...    0
01-12-2019 |    15   |   7    ...    0
```

Necesito obtener el valor en la columna "datetime" del primer valor que es distinto de 0 (es decir, la primera venta) y que se genere un nuevo dataframe con este valor y su diferencia en meses versus la fecha actual, como se muestra a continuación (considerando que estamos en enero de 2020):

```
Product  | fist sell   | dif
Product1 | 01-07-2019  | 5
Product2 | 01-02-2019  | 11
.        |    .        |  .
.        |    .        |  .
.        |    .        |  .
ProductN | Not launched| Not Launched
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si adjuntas lo que llevas intentado hasta el momento los usuarios te podrán ayudar mejor. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Datos de entrada

Crearé un dataframe de ejemplo sobre el que trabajar:

```
import pandas as pd

data={
    '2019-01-01':[0,0,0],
    '2019-02-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-03-01':[0,6,0],
    '2019-04-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-05-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-06-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-07-01':[12,4,0],
    '2019-08-01':[0,7,0],
    '2019-09-01':[16,0,0],
    '2019-10-01':[15,2,0],
    '2019-11-01':[18,6,0],
    '2019-12-01':[15,7,0],
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index", 
        columns=["Product{}".format(n) for n in range(1, 4)])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Observa que he hecho que el índice sea la columna de fechas, y que las he convertido a tipo `datetime`. Este es el dataframe de momento:

```
            Product1  Product2  Product3
2019-01-01         0         0         0
2019-02-01         0         5         0
2019-03-01         0         6         0
2019-04-01         0         5         0
2019-05-01         0         5         0
2019-06-01         0         5         0
2019-07-01        12         4         0
2019-08-01         0         7         0
2019-09-01        16         0         0
2019-10-01        15         2         0
2019-11-01        18         6         0
2019-12-01        15         7         0
```

## Obtener la fecha de la primera venta

Elijo todas las celdas con valor distinto de cero, calculo su suma acumulada y me quedo con el mínimo de esas sumas acumuladas, que corresponden a la celda en la que un dato numérico aparece por primera vez. Obtengo el índice correspondiente a ese caso, y eso me da la fecha en la que eso ocurre. Ya que el resultado es de tipo `datetime`, que contiene también la hora y eso no me interesa, me quedo sólo con la parte `.date`:

```
>>> df[df!=0].cumsum().idxmin().dt.date
Product1   2019-07-01
Product2   2019-02-01
Product3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

pero eso puedo convertirlo en un DataFrame, y renombrar la columna para que sea "first sell":

```
result = pd.DataFrame(df[df!=0].cumsum().idxmin().dt.date).rename({0: "first sell"}, axis=1)
```

## Obtener el número de meses

A este dataframe añado la columna con el número de meses trasncurridos. Este número lo obtengo dividiendo entre 30 el número de días transcurridos, el cual sale de una resta entre la fecha actual y la que tengo en la columna "first sell". Finalmente reemplazo los `NaT` ("not a date") por la cadena "Not Launched":

```
import datetime

result["dif"] = (datetime.date.today() - result["first sell"]).dt.days//30
result = result.fillna("Not Launched")
```

Este es el resultado:

```
            first sell           dif
Product1    2019-07-01           6
Product2    2019-02-01           11
Product3  Not Launched  Not Launched
```

Comment: Vaya destreza con el pandas :) ... Al ejecutarlo me da un error con la instrucción `datetime.date.now()`: `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'now'`, he probado con `from datetime import datetime` pero aún lo lío más... ¿sabes qué podrá ser?

Comment: Ups... edité el código con respecto a una versión previa que mostraba la hora como parte de la fecha, para quitarle eso, y se me quedó ese residuo. Debe ser `today()` en vez de `now()`. Ya lo he arreglado. Gracias por probarlo y reportar el problema, @DavidJP

Answer (score 3):

Te propongo el siguiente código:

```
from datetime import datetime

data={
    '2019-01-01':[0,0,0],
    '2019-02-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-03-01':[0,6,0],
    '2019-04-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-05-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-06-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-07-01':[12,4,0],
    '2019-08-01':[0,7,0],
    '2019-09-01':[16,0,0],
    '2019-10-01':[15,2,0],
    '2019-11-01':[18,6,0],
    '2019-12-01':[15,7,0],
}
ps={}
for f in data:
    for i in range(len(data[f])):
        if data[f][i]>0:
            indice='Product{}'.format(i+1)
            try: ps[indice]
            except:
                ps[indice]={}
                ps[indice]['first_sell']=f
                ps[indice]['dif']=round(
                    (datetime.now()-datetime.strptime(f,'%Y-%m-%d')).days/30
                )
for f in sorted(ps):
    l='{} | {} | {}'.format(f,ps[f]['first_sell'],ps[f]['dif'])
    print(l)
```

Me consta que es un poco básico en comparación con las maravillas que he visto hacer por aquí en Python, pero al menos es una primera aproximación y se podrá aprender mucho de las propuestas de mejora.

Tengo curiosidad por el origen de los datos pues, si parten de una base de datos, tal vez hubiera sido mucho más sencilla una consulta en SQL

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que fijar la columna Datetime como **índice** en caso de que no lo hayas hecho. Se hace así:

```
#inplace simplemente sirve para que lo haga en el mismo dataframe y no haga falta reasignarlo.
df.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)
```

Una vez tenemos las fechas como Indice, Pandas sabe interpretar los Datetime, por lo que sería tan sencillo como hace **slicing**:

```
#Seleccionamos del día 3 al día 8 de enero de 2019
df['2019-03-01':'2019-08-01']
```

## Desarrollo

Dejo aquí la programación de como se montaría todo

```
import pandas as pd

#me creo datos sinteticos, en este caso copiados de David
data={
    '2019-01-01':[0,0,0],
    '2019-02-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-03-01':[0,6,0],
    '2019-04-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-05-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-06-01':[0,5,0],
    '2019-07-01':[12,4,0],
    '2019-08-01':[0,7,0],
    '2019-09-01':[16,0,0],
    '2019-10-01':[15,2,0],
    '2019-11-01':[18,6,0],
    '2019-12-01':[15,7,0],
}

#lo introducimos en este caso en el Dataframe y transponemos para tener las fechas como indice
df_temporal = pd.DataFrame(data).T

#hacemos slicing por fecha y nos da los resultados del 3 al 8
df['2019-03-01':'2019-08-01']
```

Comment: Me gustaría reproducir tu solución, ¿cómo introduces el dataset? ¿Cómo calculas la diferencia y la primera ocurrencia?

Comment: Hola @DavidJP he desarrollado más la pregunta debajo escogiendo los datos que pones como ejemplo!

Comment: La verdad es que el `pandas` hace casi magia, con bucles parece que vamos a pedales... lo que no termino de ver en tu solución es lo que pide el OP: que localice el primer mes que cada artículo es vendido, así como hace cuántos meses... estoy usando `print(df['2019-03-01':'2019-08-01'].T)`